# venmo setup for devs outside usa

Tags: paypal, venmo

Hey i have been trying to develop solutions for venmo. I used the html checkout code from venmo integrations tab in paypal dev dashboard. I see the venmo button i click it and venmo sandbox opens , no app switch occurs as per the flow.

My test setup -  based outside USA , using. a vpn  simulating USA location
created a business account in USA on paypal.

I tried the vpn and went through the docs . did not find anything even configured the webhooks on my sandbox , the payload shows no sign of venmo payment

[doc link followed](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/pay-with-venmo/integrate/)
[demo link](https://www.loom.com/share/18bc77e78860406c9f76b0fc257dd481)

Answer (score 0):

Venmo doesn't operate in the sandbox. When clicking a venmo button, the window opens and tells you that it's working. That means: it's working.

You can test PayPal payments in the sandbox. If sandbox PayPal payments do not show in the receiving sandbox business account or do not result in webhooks being sent, this is because your integration is not configured with the correct credentials or your webhooks are not subscribed and set up correctly for that same app/client ID.

Why you are using webhooks to begin with is another matter. A server-side integration with the v2/checkout/orders API and paired with [buttons for approving the order](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) gives an immediate notification of success or failure. There's no reason to wait for or be dependent on a separate webhook notification.